# .progress does not see updated scope value from .error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to show a progress bar for multiple file upload, but I want it to reset to 0 if the server rejects it for whatever reason

I have the following code that is triggered when inputs are selected using `angular-file-upload`:

```
$scope.start = function(index) {
    $scope.errors = null;
    $scope.progress[index] = 0;
    $scope.upload[index] = $upload.upload({
        url: API_URL.url + API_URL.loc + 'shop/upload/file',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {},
        useXDomain: true,
        data: {entry_id: 1, resource_type: 'file', resource_content_type: 'image', resource: $scope.selectedFiles[index], auth_token: UserService.token},
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.errors = null;
        $scope.uploadResult.push(response.data.result);
    }, function(failure) {
        $scope.errors = failure.data;
    }, function(evt) {
        if(angular.isUndefined($scope.errors) || $scope.errors === null) {
            $scope.progress[index] = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        } else {
            $scope.progress[index] = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

However, when I set `$scope.errors = failure;` in `error`, it's too late because it always goes into `function(evt)` first. So everything ends up showing at 0% progress.

My understanding is the files have to be sending to the server before the server can reject it, which is why `$scope.errors` is set too late.

I tried changing it a bit to use `.then`, `.error`, `.progress` instead, but to no avail.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `angular-file-upload` but are you sure you want `scope.errors == null` (first line of `then`)?

Comment: @AndyGaskell Good eye! That was a typo. Updated post.

Comment: @theintellects you mentioned uploading multiple files, but you're setting $scope.errors individually on every upload item. Unless you're updating the user on upload status separately for each file, you might want to consider using something like errors[index] so all file errors are tracked instead.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned uploading multiple files, but you're setting $scope.errors individually on every upload item.

Unless you're updating the user on upload status separately for each file, you might want to consider using something like errors[index] *(see below)* so all file errors are tracked instead.

Also, because you will always get `evt` before you get `failure`, you can do the check/set for `$scope.progress[index]` after all that is done. Your progress bar will go up to 100, but it will go back down to 0.

**Also note** that we create the `$scope.errors` array on line 2 so setting `$scope.errors[index]` later on will not result in an error.

As a sidenote:

```
} else {
    $scope.errors[index] = null;
}
```

I don't think the `else` is needed anymore now because we set `errors` everytime `$scope.start` is called.

```
$scope.start = function(index) {
    $scope.errors = []; // Create errors array so we can set each index later on
    $scope.progress[index] = 0;
    $scope.upload[index] = $upload.upload({
        url: API_URL.url + API_URL.loc + 'shop/upload/file',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {},
        useXDomain: true,
        data: {entry_id: 1, resource_type: 'file', resource_content_type: 'image', resource: $scope.selectedFiles[index], auth_token: UserService.token},
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.uploadResult.push(response.data.result);
    }, function(failure) {
        $scope.errors[index] = failure.data;
    }, function(evt) {
            $scope.progress[index] = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
    }).then(function(){ // After everything else is done
        if(!(angular.isUndefined($scope.errors[index]) || $scope.errors[index] === null))
            $scope.progress[index] = 0; // Set progress back to 0 if there's an error
    });
}
```